# Match string that doesn't contain a specific word

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I'm working with ruby with the `match` method and I want to match an URL that doesn't contain a certain string with a regular Expression:
ex:

```
http://website1.com/url_with_some_words.html
http://website2.com/url_with_some_other_words.html
http://website3.com/url_with_the_word_dog.html
```

I want to match the URLs that doesn't contain the word `dog`, so the 1st and the 2nd ones should be matched

Comment: This question is best answered on posting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) Searching SO for similar questions is a good idea.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead `^(?!.*dog).*$`.

**Explanation**

- `^` : match begin of line
- `(?!.*dog)` : negative lookahead, check if the word dog doesn't exist
- `.*` : match everything (except newlines in this case)
- `$` : match end of line

[Online demo](http://rubular.com/r/hGzndqgBeg)

Comment: Wow, this piece of info was surprisingly difficult to find.

Answer (score 9):

Just use

```
string !~ /dog/
```

to select strings you need.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually an incredibly simple way to do this, using select.

```
array_of_urls.select { |url| !url.match(/dog/) }
```

this will return an array of the url's that don't contain the word 'dog' anywhere in it.

Comment: More succinctly, `array_of_urls.reject { |url| url.match(/dog/) }`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can use is:

```
!url['dog']
```

With your example:

```
array = []
array << 'http://website1.com/url_with_some_words.html'
array << 'http://website2.com/url_with_some_other_words.html'
array << 'http://website3.com/url_with_the_word_dog.html'

array.select { |url| !url['dog'] }
```

You could also reject the urls that *do* contain `'dog'`:

```
array.reject { |url| url['dog'] }
```