# Regex to find X words only when a word doesn't exist

Tags: regex, webstorm

I'm trying to do some code refactoring and as I'm doing quite a lot I'm using WebStorm's regex find in files to see which files still need refactoring.

I know this `(?:^|(?=[^']).\b)(this.user|this.isVatRegistered|showStatsInNet)\b` will show all files with one of those bits of code in.

And according to this post: [Match string that doesn't contain a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653942/match-string-that-doesnt-contain-a-specific-word/17797426#17797426) `^(?!.*UserMixin).*$` should do a negative look ahead to match only when that word doesn't exist.

My problem is I don't know how to combine them. Would someone be able to provide some guidance please?

I've tried combining like so: `(?:^|(?=[^']).\b)(?!.*UserMixin)(this.user|this.isVatRegistered|showStatsInNet)\b` but to no avail.

**TL;DR** How do I match on X number of words only when another word isn't present?

Comment: Combining them like this could work - `(?:^|(?=[^']).\b)(?!.*UserMixin)(this.user|this.isVatRegistered|showStatsInNet)\b`.

Comment: @Kamehameha I tried that before posting but it doesn't work. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Try `\A(?![\d\D]*?UserMixin)[\d\D]*?\b(?:this\.(?:user|isVatRegistered)|showStatsInNet)\b`

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Please post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with a negative lookahead then try to match those sub-strings:

```
\A(?![\d\D]*?UserMixin)[\d\D]*?\b(?:this\.(?:user|isVatRegistered)|showStatsInNet)\b
```

This would be time consuming though since there are two `[\d\D]*?` occurrences that will move the cursor character by character to the end of file content.